# CGAL CDT Default Parameters

Tags: c++, cgal, triangulation

I'm constructing a terrain with constains that can intercept themselves, so I need to change the third  parameter of CDT to `CGAL::Exact_intersections_tag`. I'm getting trouble to find the first default parameter, I found in documentation that the second is `CGAL::Default` (is this correct?) but I could not find the first. The template is:

`typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2 <CDT> CT;`

the construction should be:

`CT ct(???,CGAL::Default, CGAL::Exact_intersections_tag);`

Can anyone please tell-me how to set the first default parameter?

Comment: Did you check the examples, say constrained.cpp for instance?

Comment: Thank you for you answer Marc Glisse.
Yes I did but is still ocurring exceptions on my code. I suppouse that the only reason for exception occurs on CDT::insert_constraint is because the constraints crossing each other but it seems that there are other reasons. I will post another question depicting this problem. Thank you

Comment: You  can just write   `CT ct;`